# Regular field expression to validate alpha-numeric values,@and dot

Tags: asp.net

How can I customize regular expression to allow alpha-numeric values,@ and dot.
I want this expression for the field user name. So it should allow only those values that are present in usual usernames.
Thanks in advance...

Comment: @Andreas Niedermair..I tried [a-zA-Z0-9\.\@]+

Comment: and what was the problem with that? (apart from the backslashes that are not needed within [] it looks fine). By the way: please extend your question with those details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're asking for in your question is:

```
ValidationExpression="^[a-zA-Z0-9.@]{0,25}$"
```

But I would suggest you to use this one:

```
xyz\\\\[a-zA-Z]\d[a-zA-Z]\d{4}
```